# URL parse and match

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

How can I use the code bellow to check if the domain is a real match.

For that domain and url is going to return true, but is going to work for this `url = http://www.text-apple.com/uk/` to, which is not a true match.

But it should be a match in this case `url = http://itunes.apple.com"`, so i need to add something like if there is a `.` before the domain name then is a match.

```
domain = "apple.com"
url = "http://www.apple.com/uk/"

def domain_is_URL?(url, domain)
 d = Regexp.escape(domain)
 URI.parse(url).host.match(d)
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Helpful hint, urls are mighty similar to file paths

Comment: What do you mean "a real match"?

Comment: I gave that example there `text-apple.com/uk/` is not the real `apple.com`, it is a different website

Comment: The way the code got split made it confusing, but I see that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try comparing host components:

```
domain_parts = domain.split('.')

URI.parse(url).host.split('.').last(domain_parts.length) == domain_parts.length
```

This compares the last N parts of the URI host to see if they're the same. `[ 'text-apple', 'com' ]` is not equal to `[ 'apple', 'com' ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Radix tree to build your list of domains, then evaluate parts of your URL against the radix tree.